# How to import swagger OpenAPI json definition file to APIGateway with python CDK?

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am currently trying to get a 800-line Swagger 3.0 OpenAPI definition file to integrate into API Gateway and I am having issues.

I have tried using the SpecRestAPI API class, tried to upload the json to a S3 bucket and have not yet succeded. Would anyone please provide me with a direction to how i would be able to bring about this implementation with CDK python? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please add a minimal code example and error details to your question.

Comment: Does this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-open-api.html) give you a lead?